How to append something to the request object in NextJS middleware?
In the NextJS middleware file I am trying to add the user property to the request object. But it's not working. I checked the NextJS middleware docs and found no mention of any hiccups when trying to do this action. Would appreciate some input. Thank you
const middleware = async(request: NextRequest) => {
    try {
        const authenticationToken = request.cookies.get('authentication-token')?.value;
        if (!authenticationToken) {
            throw new Error
        }
        const userValue = jwt.verify(token);
        request.user = decoded; // This is not working
        return NextResponse.next();
    }   
    catch(error) {
        return NextResponse.json({msg: 'Not allowed here!'}, {status: 401});
    }
}

// export const config = {
//     matcher: [
        
//     ]
// };

export default middleware;

